# Flip textPath without changing path d attribute

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I have a `textPath` as such:

```css
body{
  padding-left:10rem;
}
```

```html
<svg style="overflow:visible">

  <path id="path1" stroke="black" d="M 0 0 L -100 100" stroke-width="3" />
  <text font-size="24" dy="-10" text-anchor="middle">
    <textPath href="#path1"startOffset="50%">Hello there</textPath>
    <textPath href="#path1" startOffset="50%" dominant-baseline="central">➤</textPath>
  </text>
</svg>
```

I need to simply invert the text such that it aligns like this:
[image]

and I'm trying to do so without changing M & L of the `d` attribute of path, how do I achieve this?

Comment: Your only option is therefore side="right" and stick to Firefox because that's the only browser that supports side

Comment: @RobertLongson is there no other way? because obviously I'll need cross browser support

Comment: You could always download the source code to Chromium and implement support for the side attribute. I imagine you'd do it in a similar way to the way I implemented support in Firefox.

Comment: @RobertLongson could you provide me with links so I can look into it?

Comment: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1446650 good luck with Chromium